# What causes a TU to be included in compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, macros, visual-studio-2010

I am a little out of my depth here, I'll be honest.

I am doing some rather curious experimentation, having pre-main functions register my classes in a factory, through anonymous namespaces. Until recently, adding the following to a class definition (.cpp) would do the trick.

```
namespace { int x = Register<classType>(className); }
```

This would be wrapped in a macro and 'Register' would pass the type and name off to my factory.

This worked fine and every class that included this macro was getting registered, until I went to move the code into a static library. Now, since the classes are only referenced by the factory, it looks like they're being omitted from the build - my 'Register' functions are no longer being called and so my factory is empty.

I have managed to fix this by moving all my macros into the constructor of a manager object, but I noticed that as soon as I referenced them there, the macros in the .cpp files started getting called again. I guessed because now the classes are actually being referenced by something.

However, I don't really want to do it this way and I can't seem to find a non-committal way of referencing the classes in the constructor (e.g `class ClassToRegister;`) which includes them in the build, so that my register macros will get called.

Firstly, does this make sense?

Secondly, any advice on how I can force these TUs to compile so that the anonymous namespaces 'kick in' at runtime?

Comment: (a) show us how you built the static library? (b) read up on [static initialization order fiasco](addressing this question)

Comment: TU: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming) - in this instance, it's a class represented by a .h and a .cpp file.

I suspect that this is a product of IOF, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is part and parcel of using static libraries; unused code will not make it through without linker voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

A static library is a bunch of object files you give the linker saying "hey, find here what I didn't define elsewhere". So if a given object file in the library doesn't fill a dependency, you won't be able to include it in your program without relying on other features of the linker (for instance some linkers have a way to include all the object files of static libraries instead of only the one who fill dependencies).

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you are a victim of aggressive optimisation, but with a reason : since you do not use objects in a nameless namespace, the compiler removes them.

You could try to get around like this :

```
namespace foo
{
namespace{
MACRO_TO_DEFINE_VARIABLE( MyClass ); // define a variable named registrationObj
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
  (void)registrationObj;
}
}
```